Webcam pure black in all apps except for webcamoid on Manjaro
I am on Manjaro linux 24 and recently got a Poly Studio P5 webcam for cheap. It worked flawlessly out of the box in webcamoid but when I try to use it in firefox, chromium, zoom or cameractrls I get various issues. Most of the apps just show a black feed, some don't work outright. Most apps can see the webcam, just not the feed.

When using webcamoid the light on the camera lights up, when using anything else it doesn't.

I am in the video usergroup.
The shutter isn't closed


In Webcamoid, try changing the video format, e.g., MJPG, YUYV, RGB16, etc. See https://github.com/webcamoid/akvcam/wiki/Configure-the-cameras
